# Struggling with a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, timer, nullpointerexception, countdown

Total newbie programmer here trying to make his first Android app.  A simple countdown timer and a few other things and it was all working, but in order to try and fix an issue with the countdown timer I moved that section of code from within the Start Button onClick into the onCreate of the activity(or at least I think I have).  In my head I think that means that the countdown timer is ready to run, but won't actually run until the user hits the Start Button.

Anyway, with the code below I'm getting a NullPointerException when the activity loads and I'm not sure where, or if anything I have done is remotely good programming (I've watched a lot of YouTube vids recently and got a lot of help from other questions here).

Any help would be very well received :)

```
package com.asurya.hulktimer;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class main extends Activity {

    long starttime = 180000;
    long count = 1000;
    long timechange = 30000;
int missionpoints = 0;
boolean isPaused = false;
boolean clockrunning = false;

Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Clock is running - create some pause code";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;




/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.layout.main);


 // THIS SECTION ENABLES THE FEEDBACK FOR ALL THE BUTTONS

    final Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

 // THIS SECTION DEFINES THE FONT FOR ALL THE OBJECTS IN THE VIEW       

   final Button but_start = (Button) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.but_start);
   Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "CASLANTR.TTF");
   but_start.setTypeface(font);

   final Button but_reset = (Button) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.but_reset);
   but_reset.setTypeface(font);

   final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.timer);
   txt.setText(formatTime(starttime));
   txt.setTypeface(font);

   final TextView txt_mt_1 = (TextView)      findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.lbl_missiontally_1);
   txt_mt_1.setTypeface(font);

   final TextView txt_mt_2 = (TextView) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.lbl_missiontally_2);
   txt_mt_2.setTypeface(font);

   final TextView txt_mt_value = (TextView) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.lbl_mt_value);
   txt_mt_value.setTypeface(font);

   final TextView txt_cp_value = (TextView) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.lbl_cp_value);
   txt_cp_value.setTypeface(font);

   final Button but_add_time = (Button) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.but_add);
   but_add_time.setTypeface(font);

   final Button but_minus_time = (Button) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.but_minus);
   but_minus_time.setTypeface(font);

   final Button but_generate_cp = (Button) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.but_generate_cp);
   but_generate_cp.setTypeface(font);

   final Button but_mp_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_mp_add);
   but_mp_add.setTypeface(font);

   final Button but_mp_minus = (Button) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.but_mp_minus);
   but_mp_minus.setTypeface(font);

   final Button but_mp_reset = (Button) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.but_mp_reset);
   but_mp_reset.setTypeface(font);

   {

       //  THIS SECTION IS THE COMMAND POINTS CODE

       final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.generate);

       Button but_generate_cp1 = (Button) findViewById(com.asurya.hulktimer.R.id.but_generate_cp);
       but_generate_cp1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            vibe.vibrate(50);
            mp.start();

            final Random random = new Random();
            int mycps  = random.nextInt(6);
            final int myCommandPoints = mycps + 1;

            txt_cp_value.setText("" + String.valueOf(myCommandPoints));
        }
    });
   }

   // THIS SECTION IS THE COUNTDOWN TIMER

   final MediaPlayer oneminrem = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ping);

   final CountDownTimer gameclock = new CountDownTimer(starttime, count) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        txt.setText("" + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));

        long oneMinuteRemaining = millisUntilFinished /1000;

        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 60){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 30){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 15){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 10){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 9){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 8){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 7){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 6){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 5){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 4){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 3){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 2){
            oneminrem.start();
        }
        if (oneMinuteRemaining == 1){
            oneminrem.start();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        txt.setText("00:00");
        but_start.setText("Start");
        clockrunning = false;
    }
};

// THIS SECTION IS THE TIMER BUTTONS

    Button but_start1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_start);
    but_start1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        vibe.vibrate(50);

        if (clockrunning = false) {
            gameclock.start();
        }

        if (clockrunning = true) {

            // Display a Toast message to confirm code working.
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

        }
    });




       Button but_reset1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_reset);
   but_reset1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vibe.vibrate(50);
        if (clockrunning == true){

        }
    }
});



   //THIS SECTIONS IS THE BUTTONS WHICH ADD OR SUBTRACT TIME FROM THE STARTING TIME

   Button but_add1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_add);
   but_add1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vibe.vibrate(50);
        if (clockrunning == false) {
        starttime = starttime + timechange;
        txt.setText(formatTime(starttime));
        }

    }
});

   Button but_minus1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_minus);
   but_minus1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vibe.vibrate(50);
        if (clockrunning == false) {
        starttime = starttime - timechange;
        txt.setText(formatTime(starttime));
        }

    }
});


   //THIS SECTION HANDLES THE MISSIONS POINTS CODE

   txt_mt_value.setText("" + String.valueOf(missionpoints));

   Button but_missionpoint_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_mp_add);
   but_missionpoint_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vibe.vibrate(50);
        missionpoints = missionpoints + 1;
        txt_mt_value.setText("" + String.valueOf(missionpoints));

    }
});

   Button but_missionpoint_minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_mp_minus);
   but_missionpoint_minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vibe.vibrate(50);
        missionpoints = missionpoints - 1;
        txt_mt_value.setText("" + String.valueOf(missionpoints));
    }
});

   Button but_missionpoints_reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_mp_reset);
   but_missionpoints_reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vibe.vibrate(50);
        missionpoints = 0;
        txt_mt_value.setText("" + String.valueOf(missionpoints));
    }
});
}

    /* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#finish()
 */
@Override
public void finish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.finish();
}

public String formatTime(long millis) {
 //   String output = "00:00";
    long seconds = millis / 1000;
    long minutes = seconds / 60;

    seconds = seconds % 60;
    minutes = minutes % 60;

    String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
    String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);

    if (seconds < 10)
      secondsD = "0" + seconds;
    if (minutes < 10)
      minutesD = "0" + minutes;

    String output = minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
    return output;
  }  

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Info:
    Intent myInfoMenuIntent = new Intent(main.this, Info.class);
    startActivity(myInfoMenuIntent);
        return true;
    case R.id.Credits:
        Intent myCreditMenuIntent = new Intent(main.this, Credits.class);
        startActivity(myCreditMenuIntent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: And more importantly, look at the first line of the stack trace, note the line number it references, and tell us what that line is.

Comment: Assuming you're using eclipse with ADT: if you use logcat in DDMS, you can just double-click the line which shows the Exception. This will point you to the place of the error directly, so you can solve it very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

A null pointer exception in a line of type

A.B.C.D

means that either

- A is null
- or A.B is null
- or A.B.C is null

Something at the left of a point is null.

So provide intermedite variables and print them in console to detect which is null.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Thanks. probably a stack trace can better explain the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Think about making your UI elements (e.g. txt_cp_value) member variables of the class and then assign them in the onCreate method.  That way they'll be accessible from the anonymous OnClickListener.  From what I can see, `txt_cp_value.setText("" + String.valueOf(myCommandPoints));` could be the culprit.

Have you got the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

"A simple countdown timer and a few other things and it was all working, but in order to try and fix an issue with the countdown timer I moved that section of code from within the Start Button onClick into the onCreate of the activity"

If this is true, then most likely the code which you moved to the onCreate method tries to use something which is not initialized in the onCreate method, but it was initialized in the start button onClick method. Look for something like this in your code.

About the code. This is far from efficient:

```
if (oneMinuteRemaining == 60){
    oneminrem.start();
}
if (oneMinuteRemaining == 30){
    oneminrem.start();
}
```

You should use 'else if' after the first 'if' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Clock is running - create some pause code";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
```

Was the guilty code.  Relocated it inside the button onClick listener.  That's just temporary code for testing something anyway.

Thanks for all the help again guys.  I now know more about Java and stack traces than I did yesterday :)